# Touches(Gestures) not getting recognized on part of screen where there is a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to be able to handle the gestures that happen on all parts of my screen not just on the part thats not covered by the UITableView.

Is this possible? And if so how can I get it working?

Here is my code that I use to collect the touch data. I though having this line

```
UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
```

would allow me to collect all touches.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint currentPosition = [t locationInView:self.view];

CGFloat positionDelta = currentPosition.x-_originalTouchPosition.x;

if (positionDelta > 50.0)
{
    NSLog(@"X");
}
else if (positionDelta < -50.0)
{
    NSLog(@"Y");
}
else if (positionDelta > 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Z");
}
else 
{
    return;
}
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
_originalTouchPosition = [t locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"touches began");
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"tocuhes ended");
}
```

Many Thanks,
-Code

Comment: You can use a UITapGestureRecognizer and add it to the view, so the non editable components (not like UITextField and those) will receive all the events (even UITableView) but the bad part is that it will lock the native events of those components. So, try passing the tap event to the right UI element. I know it's not a full solution but maybe you can see if this could work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass your UITableViewCell and apply the `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method in that subclass, then you will be able to detect the touch on your UITableView as well as you have the normal functionality of UITableView available.